# How to implement a zoomable UIPageViewController when in Two Pages mode?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, landscape, uipageviewcontroller

I need to implement a zoomable UIPageViewController in iOS 5 when in a two pages layout mode (in other words, when the Spine Location is set to Mid).

Using a scrollview for each page works fine when only one page is displayed. But when two pages are diplayed side-by-side in landscape mode, how can one seamless synch the pages and align the borders during the zoom animation?

One possible solution would be to put the UIPageViewController inside a bigger UIScrollView controller, but this yelds a blurred image because the two scrollviews inside the pages are not updated with a higer resolution area of the source images when the parent is zoomed.

It seems that is impossible to zoom inside a UIPageViewController when in two page mode. Is there someone who found a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am still testing, but I have this.
I used the pageviewcontroller template.
I changed the scene to show a image instead a month (inside a UIImageView).

used a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to zoom the image and an UIPanGestureRecognizer to move the image once it is zoomed and it works.

The only problem is sometimes the page swipe is recognised instead the pan, so it changes the page instead moving the inside image.
And it only zooms a page at a time, I marked clip subviews in the view of the dataViewController, so 2 pages remains the same size even when you zoom in the other.