# Zooming in UIPageViewController with spineLocation:mid

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, landscape, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a PDF reader with neat page-turning animations AND zooming for two-page exhibition on a landscape mode iPad.

I was able to do this partially by creating a `UIScrollView` with the `UIPageViewController` inside it. The user was able to turn the pages naturally and use pinch to zoom. But then two problems arose and, despite a lot of effort [looking through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052553/how-to-implement-a-zoomable-uipageviewcontroller-when-in-two-pages-mode) StackOverFlow, Apple's Documentation and many other places, I was unable to find what I needed.

**1. I wasn't able to redraw the PDF with the right resolution inside the `PageViewController` while zooming.**

While debugging, I found out that the custom `drawRect` function that I used to draw the PDF was receiving the same default size it always received without zooming. Even though the page's `frame` now was way bigger than the whole iPad screen, the `setNeedsDisplay` function kept sending requests to redraw the PDF on a mere 500x700px `rect`. So, the image was always blurry.

When I tried to manually change the page's `frame` inside the `PageViewController`, I ended up with some really weird behaviour, and the pages were only rendered correctly when I navigated forward and backwards again on the PageViewController. In other words, it didn't work.

**2. I wasn't able to ignore page turning when zoom was applied.**

The ideal would be that the `PageViewController` was unable to navigate while zooming. Once the user got back to 1:1 zoom, it would behave as any other PageViewController. Is there a way to "steal" the gesture from the PVC *only* at these certain circumstances?

I am looking for help on this, but actually thinking: Am I looking at this problem from the wrong place? Is there a better way to implement these features?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: HI @tuliomir, while this might be really late, do you have any guides on how you added the scroll to the UIPageViewController?

Comment: unfortunately no, @amitsbajaj... another developer took the project and implemented it in some other way, with the end result behaving in a way I didn't like as well. =/

Comment: Ah man what a shame! But thanks though for getting back to me on this